# Прокрутка элемента в overflow блоке

Tags: html, css

Имеется такой дизайн:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, есть переполнение справа, нужно, чтобы этот блок заканчивался там же, где и блок слева.

Попытался установить блоку справа `overflow: auto`, но обрезается часть ниже красной линии

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы весь правый блок скролился, не обрезая нижнюю часть?

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu_jobs_desktop {
  /* display: grid; */
  /* align-self: center; */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* overflow-y: auto; */
  margin-left: 181px;
  width: 354px;
}

.menu_jobs_desktop_content {
  background: #181818;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  overflow: auto;
  height: 630px;
}

.menu_jobs {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: #181818;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu_jobs_item_answer {
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 500;
  background: white;
  margin-top: 12px;
  height: 36px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px; }

.menu_jobs_title {
  color: white;
  font-size: 22px;
  width: 224px;
  margin-top: 72px;
  margin-bottom: 24px; }

.menu_jobs_item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 224px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 18px; }

.menu_jobs_item:before {
  border: 1px solid white;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  border-radius: 12px; }

.menu_jobs_item:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0; }

.menu_jobs_item_title {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 11px;
  margin-left: 11px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: white; }

.menu_jobs_item_demand {
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-left: 11px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 18px; }



.menu {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #181818;
  z-index: 1000;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: .5s;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  }

.menu__contacts_d__wrapper {
  width: 408px; }

.header__wrap-menu-block {
  cursor: pointer; }


.menu__container {
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: left;
  color: white; }

.menu__item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 9px 10px;
  height: 38px;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  font-size: 16px; }

.menu__item:nth-of-type(7) {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0; }

.menu__item:last-of-type {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-right: 32px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  height: 44px; }

.menu__triangle {
  margin-left: 10px; }

.menu__item__rectangle {
  width: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 2px;
  top: 7px;
  background: white;
  transition-property: width;
  transition-duration: .5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in; }

.menu__item__text {
  line-height: 20px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center; }


.menu__back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: 6px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 115px;
  height: 36px;
  color: #8c8c8c;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; }


body {
  touch-action: none; }

.menu__main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  }



@media (min-width: 360px) {
  .menu_jobs_title {
    margin-top: 82px;
    margin-bottom: 28px;
    font-size: 26px;
    width: 248px; }
  .menu_jobs_item {
    width: 248px;
    margin-bottom: 20px; }
  .menu_jobs_item_title {
    padding-top: 13px;
    margin-left: 13px;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 7px; }
  .menu__item {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 42px; }
  .menu__item__text {
    height: 22px; }
  .menu__item:last-of-type {
    width: 203px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    height: 50px; }
  .menu__triangle {
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    margin-left: 14px; }
  .menu__container {
    width: 203px; }
 
  .menu__item__rectangle {
    top: 8px; }
  

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .menu_jobs_item_answer {
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 21px;
    margin-top: 18px; }
  .menu_jobs_title {
    margin-top: 112px;
    width: 408px;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 36px; }
  .menu_jobs_item_demand {
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-left: 17px;
    line-height: 26px; }
  .menu_jobs_item {
    border-radius: 14px;
    width: 408px;
    margin-bottom: 24px; }
  .menu_jobs_item_title {
    padding-top: 17px;
    margin-left: 17px;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-bottom: 9px; }
  .menu__item {
    font-size: 24px;
    height: 54px;
    margin-bottom: 23px;
    padding: 12px; }
  .menu__container {
    width: 271px; }
  .menu__item:last-of-type {
    margin-top: 105px;
    width: 271px;
    height: 64px; }
  .menu__triangle {
    top: 23px;
    right: 14px; }
  }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .menu__question__title {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 50px; }
  .menu__question__introduce, .menu__question__contacts {
    margin-bottom: 25px; }
  .menu__item {
    font-size: 24px; }
  .menu__container {
    width: 271px; }
  .menu__item:last-of-type {
    margin-top: 105px;
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    width: 271px; }
  .menu__triangle {
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px; }
  .menu__contacts_d__content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; }
  .menu__question__active {
    font-size: 11px !important; }
  .menu__question__comment__wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 141px; }
  .menu__question__comment_text {
    font-size: 14px; }
  .menu__question__send {
    float: right;
    width: 129px;
    font-size: 14px; }
  .menu__contacts__phone {
    margin-top: 82px;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 12px; }
  .menu__contacts__email {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    height: auto; }
  .menu__contacts__years {
    font-size: 16px; }
  .menu__item__rectangle {
    top: 12px; }
  .menu__item:nth-of-type(7) .menu__item__rectangle {
    top: 13px; }
  .menu__thanks-back {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    border-radius: 29px; }
  .menu__thanks-back-text {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 17px 95px;
    text-transform: uppercase; }
  .thanks__title-text {
    font: 600 66px 'Montserrat Alternates'; }
  .thanks__title-descr-text {
    font: 500 22px / 29.7px 'Montserrat Alternates'; }
  .thanks__title-descr {
    width: 340px; }
  .menu__projects_d__item_type {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; }
  .menu__projects_d__item_type::before {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 5px;
    bottom: 16px;
    left: 16px;
    right: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0px -2px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); }
  .menu__projects_d__item {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.252038);
    height: 345px; }
  .menu__projects_d__item_img {
    height: 301px; } }

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .menu_jobs_item_title {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding-top: 18px;
    margin-left: 18px; }
  .menu_jobs_item_demand {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px; }
  .menu_jobs_item {
    width: 374px;
    margin-bottom: 27px; }
  .menu_jobs_item_answer {
    height: 57px;
    color: black; }
  .menu_jobs_desktop {
    width: 374px; }
  .menu_jobs_desktop_content {
    height: 486px;
    }
  .menu_jobs_title {
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 100%; }
  .menu__item__rectangle {
    top: 8px; }
  .menu__item:nth-of-type(7) .menu__item__rectangle {
    top: 12px; }
  .menu__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    position: relative;
    left: -10px;
    width: 758px;
    height: 486px; }
  .menu__item {
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 42px;
    margin-bottom: 22px;
    padding: 10px; }
  .menu__item__text {
    font-size: 18px; }
  .menu__item:nth-of-type(6) {
    margin: 0; }
  .menu__item:nth-of-type(7) {
    width: 203px;
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 74px;
    height: 50px; }
  .menu__triangle {
    margin-left: 14px;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px; }
  }

@media (min-width: 1366px) {
  .menu_jobs_desktop {
    width: 403px; }
  .menu_jobs_desktop_content {
    height: 468px; }
  .menu_jobs_item {
    width: 403px;
    min-height: 154px;
    max-height: 180px; }
  .menu_jobs_item:before {
    border-radius: 14px; }
  .menu_jobs_item_title {
    padding-top: 18px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 1.53; }
  .menu_jobs_item_demand {
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    line-height: 1.53; }
  .menu_jobs_item_answer {
    height: 57px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 14px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 14px; }
  .menu_jobs_title {
    font-size: 32px;
    margin-bottom: 35px; }
  .menu_jobs_desktop {
    margin-left: 210px; }
  .menu__container {
    width: 816px;
    height: 468px; }
  .menu__item:nth-of-type(7) {
    margin-top: 56px; }
  }
  

@media (min-width: 1920px) {
  .menu__item {
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 44px;
    margin-bottom: 26px; }
  .menu__item__text {
    font-size: 20px; }
  .menu__item:nth-of-type(7) .menu__item__rectangle {
    top: 12px; }
  .menu__item:nth-of-type(7) {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 11px;
    margin-top: 140px;
    width: 226px;
    height: 54px; }
  .menu__triangle {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-left: 16px; }
  .menu__container {
    width: 1030px;
    height: 589px; }
  .menu_jobs_desktop {
    margin-left: 300px;
    width: 1000000000px; }
  .menu_jobs_item {
    width: 515px;
    margin-bottom: 28px;
    min-height: 184px;
    max-height: 214px; }
  .menu_jobs_title {
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-bottom: 48px; }
  .menu_jobs_item_title {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-top: 27px;
    margin-left: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 12px; }
   }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <!-- Главное окно -->
    <div class="menu__main">
      <div class="menu__main_container">
        <div class="menu__container">
          <div class="menu_main_left">
            <div class="menu__item bg-gray">
              <span class="menu__item__text">Проекты</span>
              <div class="menu__item__rectangle"></div>
            </div><br>
            <div class="menu__item bg-gray">
              <span class="menu__item__text">Услуги</span>
              <div class="menu__item__rectangle"></div>
            </div><br>
            <div class="menu__item bg-gray">
              <span class="menu__item__text">Поддержка</span>
              <div class="menu__item__rectangle"></div>
            </div><br>
            <div class="menu__item bg-gray">
              <span class="menu__item__text">Контакты</span>
              <div class="menu__item__rectangle"></div>
            </div><br>
            <div class="menu__item bg-gray">
              <span class="menu__item__text">Вакансии</span>
              <div class="menu__item__rectangle"></div>
            </div><br>
            <div class="menu__item bg-gray">
              <span class="menu__item__text">О нас</span>
              <div class="menu__item__rectangle"></div>
            </div><br>
            <div class="menu__item bg-gray">
              <span class="menu__item__text">Заказать проект
                <svg class="menu__triangle" width="12" height="12" viewBox="0 0 12 12" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M10.2111 6.89444L1.44721 11.2764C0.953235 11.5234 0.352562 11.3232 0.105573 10.8292C0.0361451 10.6903 0 10.5372 0 10.382V1.61804C0 1.06576 0.447715 0.618042 1 0.618042C1.15525 0.618042 1.30836 0.654187 1.44721 0.723615L10.2111 5.10558C10.7051 5.35257 10.9053 5.95324 10.6584 6.44722C10.5616 6.64075 10.4047 6.79767 10.2111 6.89444Z" fill="white" />
                </svg>
              </span>
              <div class="menu__item__rectangle"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Окно "Вакансии" для десктопа -->
          <div class="menu_jobs_desktop">
            <div class="menu_jobs_desktop_content">
              <div class="menu_jobs_title">Вакансии</div>
              <div class="menu_jobs_item">
                <div class="menu_jobs_item_title">Junior Front-end developer:</div>
                <div class="menu_jobs_item_demand">- HTML+CSS3</div>
                <div class="menu_jobs_item_demand">- Angular/React/Vue.js</div>
                <div class="menu_jobs_item_answer">ОТКЛИКНУТЬСЯ</div>
              </div>
              <div class="menu_jobs_item">
                <div class="menu_jobs_item_title">Junior Back-end developer:</div>
                <div class="menu_jobs_item_demand">- .NET/Node.js</div>
                <div class="menu_jobs_item_answer">ОТКЛИКНУТЬСЯ</div>
              </div>
              <div class="menu_jobs_item">
                <div class="menu_jobs_item_title">Web-designer:</div>
                <div class="menu_jobs_item_demand">- Векторные редакторы (Adobe XD/Figma/Sketch)</div>
                <div class="menu_jobs_item_answer">ОТКЛИКНУТЬСЯ</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[Полный код](https://codepen.io/krasav_vich/pen/maJMjj)

**UPD:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Блок должен уходить вверх и заканчиваться красной линией

Comment: код свой покажите

Comment: Прикрепил выше.

Comment: `.menu_jobs_desktop { overflow: scroll; }`

Comment: Не вышло, нужно, чтобы этот блок был видимым, но при этом скролился

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить такой пример\вариант со `sticky` позиционированием:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
 /*  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; */
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #181818;
  color:#fff;
}

.menu-inner {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 758px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu-left {
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.menu-left ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 30px 0 50px;
}

.menu-left ul>li {
  height: 42px;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
  padding: 10px;
}


.menu-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.menu-left ul+.menu-link {
  white-space:nowrap;
  height: 42px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.menu-link:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top:50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  margin-top: -5px;
}


.menu-right {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}


h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 36px;
}


.jobs-item {
  border-radius: 14px;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 27px;
  position: relative;
  border:1px solid #fff;
  padding-bottom: 57px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.jobs-bottom {
  height: 57px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.jobs-bottom>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#000;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 21px;
}

.jobs-body {
  padding: 18px;
}

.jobs-title {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin:0 0 9px;
}

.jobs-desc {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.jobs-desc ul>li {
  position: relative;
}

.jobs-desc ul>li:before {
  content: '-';
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

@media (min-width:640px){
  .menu-inner {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  
  .menu-left {
    position: sticky;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 10;
    padding-bottom: 72px;
    align-self: flex-start;
  }
  
  .menu-left ul+.menu-link {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  
  .menu-right {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu-inner">
    <div class="menu-left">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="menu-link">
            Проекты
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="menu-link">
            Услуги
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="menu-link">
            Поддержка
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="menu-link">
            Контакты
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="menu-link">
            Вакансии
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="menu-link">
            О нас
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <a href="#" class="menu-link">Заказать проект</a>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-right">
      <h3>Вакансии</h3>

      <div class="jobs-list">
        <div class="jobs-item">
          <div class="jobs-body">
            <h6 class="jobs-title">
              Junior Front-end developer:
            </h6>
            <div class="jobs-desc">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  HTML+CSS3
                </li>
                <li>
                  Angular/React/Vue.js
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="jobs-bottom">
            <a href="#">ОТКЛИКНУТЬСЯ</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="jobs-item">
          <div class="jobs-body">
            <h6 class="jobs-title">
              Junior Back-end developer:
            </h6>
            <div class="jobs-desc">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  .NET/Node.js
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="jobs-bottom">
            <a href="#">ОТКЛИКНУТЬСЯ</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="jobs-item">
          <div class="jobs-body">
            <h6 class="jobs-title">
              Web-designer:
            </h6>
            <div class="jobs-desc">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  Векторные редакторы (Adobe XD/Figma/Sketch)
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="jobs-bottom">
            <a href="#">ОТКЛИКНУТЬСЯ</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="jobs-item">
          <div class="jobs-body">
            <h6 class="jobs-title">
              Web-designer:
            </h6>
            <div class="jobs-desc">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  Векторные редакторы (Adobe XD/Figma/Sketch)
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="jobs-bottom">
            <a href="#">ОТКЛИКНУТЬСЯ</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Или такой вариант с плагином [mCustomScrollbar.](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/):

```js
$(window).load(function(){

    $(".mCustomScrollbar").mCustomScrollbar({
      theme:"minimal",
      scrollbarPosition: 'outside'
    });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #181818;
  color:#fff;
}

.menu-inner {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 758px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu-left {
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.menu-left ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 30px 0 50px;
}

.menu-left ul>li {
  height: 42px;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
  padding: 10px;
}


.menu-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.menu-left ul+.menu-link {
  white-space:nowrap;
  height: 42px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.menu-link:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top:50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  margin-top: -5px;
}


.menu-right {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}

.jobs-list {
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
}


h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 36px;
}


.jobs-item {
  border-radius: 14px;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 27px;
  position: relative;
  border:1px solid #fff;
  padding-bottom: 57px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.jobs-bottom {
  height: 57px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.jobs-bottom>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#000;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 21px;
}

.jobs-body {
  padding: 18px;
}

.jobs-title {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin:0 0 9px;
}

.jobs-desc {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.jobs-desc ul>li {
  position: relative;
}

.jobs-desc ul>li:before {
  content: '-';
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

@media (min-width:640px){
  
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  
  .menu-inner {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  
  .menu-left {
    padding-bottom: 72px;
  }
  
  .menu-right {
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .menu-left ul+.menu-link {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  
  .menu-right {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" />
  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-inner">
      <div class="menu-left">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="menu-link">
              Проекты
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="menu-link">
              Услуги
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="menu-link">
              Поддержка
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="menu-link">
              Контакты
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="menu-link">
              Вакансии
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="menu-link">
              О нас
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <a href="#" class="menu-link">Заказать проект</a>
      </div>

      <div class="menu-right ">
        <h3>Вакансии</h3>

        <div class="jobs-list mCustomScrollbar">
          <div class="jobs-item">
            <div class="jobs-body">
              <h6 class="jobs-title">
                Junior Front-end developer:
              </h6>
              <div class="jobs-desc">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    HTML+CSS3
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    Angular/React/Vue.js
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jobs-bottom">
              <a href="#">ОТКЛИКНУТЬСЯ</a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="jobs-item">
            <div class="jobs-body">
              <h6 class="jobs-title">
                Junior Back-end developer:
              </h6>
              <div class="jobs-desc">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    .NET/Node.js
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jobs-bottom">
              <a href="#">ОТКЛИКНУТЬСЯ</a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="jobs-item">
            <div class="jobs-body">
              <h6 class="jobs-title">
                Web-designer:
              </h6>
              <div class="jobs-desc">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    Векторные редакторы (Adobe XD/Figma/Sketch)
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jobs-bottom">
              <a href="#">ОТКЛИКНУТЬСЯ</a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="jobs-item">
            <div class="jobs-body">
              <h6 class="jobs-title">
                Web-designer:
              </h6>
              <div class="jobs-desc">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    Векторные редакторы (Adobe XD/Figma/Sketch)
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jobs-bottom">
              <a href="#">ОТКЛИКНУТЬСЯ</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, вариант с библиотекой помог